# Kafka Producer is not retring when Broker is Down

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have setup up Kafka using version 0.9 with the basic configuration as
 1 Broker 1 Topic and 1 Partition.

Below are Producer Configurations that I have added to enable the retry from Producer.

```
    props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 5);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, 500);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
    props.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG, 500);
    props.put(ProducerConfig.METADATA_MAX_AGE_CONFIG, 50);
```

I understand from the documents that

Setting a value greater than zero will cause the client to resend any record whose send fails with a potentially transient error. Note that this retry is no different than if the client resent the record upon receiving the error.

Both my Broker & Zookeeper are down and the retry operation is not working.

ERROR o.s.k.s.LoggingProducerListener - Exception thrown when sending a message to topic TestTopic1|
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 500 ms.

I need to know if I am missing anything here for the retry to work.

Answer (score 4):

Resend (retry) works only if you have connection to the Broker and something happened during sending a message.

So, if your Broker is dead, there is no any reason to send message at all - no connection. And that is an exception about.

Answer (score 2):

I think retries should work anyway, even if the broker is down. This is the whole reason to have retries in the first place. Could be a temporary network issue after all.

There is a bug in the Kafka 0.9.0.1 producer which causes retries not to work. [See here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3594).

Fixed in 0.9.0.2 (which is not released yet) and 0.10. I'd upgrade the broker to 0.10 and try again.

Comment: I wanted to test the retry functionality, henceforth purposely kept the broker & Zookeeper down.

Thank for pointing out this bug, Let me try updating to 0.10.

Comment: The issue remains the same even after upgrading to 0.10. Can you tell me how did it work for you. 
Can you tell me whether any other changes are required ?

Comment: Did you upgrade both producer and server? Also, how do you know it's not retrying? Also, when are you killing the broker? I think initially it needs to be there for the producer to work. You could try producing messages in a loop (with a sleep), then shutdown the broker while it is producing? Also, play with retry.backoff.ms. Maybe set it to something pretty high so you can determine it is actually retrying?

Comment: I didnt start the broker at all.
I think I need to keep the broker ON as even Artem suggested the same in the above comment. Let me try to shutdown while its producing.

Answer (score 0):

As @artem answered Kafka producer config is not designed to retry when broker is down. It only retries during transient errors which is pretty much useless to be honest. It beats me why spring-Kafka did not take care of it.
Anyways to solve the situation I handled this with @Retry config with springboot. Checkin this SO answer for details :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/65248428/6621377